# how to give same serial number for group of records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am just new in mysql. I have records like below in carts table

```
 id   code
 1     100
 2     101
 3     102
 4     100
 5     100
 6     101
```

My excepted output like below:-

```
id     code    serial_number
 1     100        1
 2     101        2
 3     102        3
 4     100        1
 5     100        1
 6     101        2
```

I want same serial number that is belongs to same group i.e code. can anyone help me how to do?

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: This is quite an interesting problem.  The answer is non-trivial.  The OP could have explained it better, but the groups are defined by starting with `code = 100`, so the solution is not trivial.

Comment: What are your requirements for a serial number? As there is obviously a 1:1 relation between serial number and code, what speaks against using the code itself as the serial number?

Comment: I'm downvoting, because my questions have been ignored. Instead of answering, kunal has aksked almost the same question again and the same questions arise of course: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527736/how-to-give-same-value-for-each-group-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Your groups are defined by starting with `code = 100`.  This is a little tricky.  In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions to define the groups and then `row_number()` to assign the `serial_number`:

```
select c.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by grp order by id) as serial_number
from (select c.*,
             sum( code = 100 ) over (order by id) as grp
      from carts c
     ) c;
```

This is much more complicated in earlier versions of MySQL.

You can identify the group using a subquery:

```
select c.*,
       (select count(*)
        from carts c2
        where c2.id <= c.id and c2.code = 100
       ) as grp
from carts c;
```

You can then use variables to get the information you want:

```
select c.*,
       (@rn := if(@g = grp, @rn + 1,
                  if(@g := grp, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as serial_number
from (select c.*,
             (select count(*)
              from carts c2
              where c2.id <= c.id and c2.code = 100
             ) as grp
      from carts c
      order by grp, id
     ) c cross join
     (select @g := -1, @rn := 0) params;
```

Comment: why you give static value 100

Comment: and my code not like start with 100 its in longs alphanumeic contains 16 words . So this might not work

Answer (score 0):

According to your example you always have the same serial number for a code. So what do you gain?

Here is the very simple query:

```
select id, code, code - 99 as serial_number
from mytable
order by id;
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: Please explain why. This does give one serial number per code.

Comment: I was thinking along exactly the same lines, for OPs data `serial_number = code - 99`. Who needs all those tricky window functions!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner my code is 16 alpnumeric . i just taken example for understanding better. No answers works for me

Comment: Have you seen my questions in the request comments? ("What are your requirements for a serial number? ...") Please answer them.