# how to give same value for each group in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i am stuck from creating mysql query from yesterday. i have one table carts like below :-

```
 id     material_code
  1         ABC100
  2         DEF200
  3         ABC100
  4         ABC100
  5         DEF200
```

Material code will 16 digits long i have taken small for better understand. i want output something like this below:-

```
 id     material_code   item_number
  1         ABC100         1
  2         DEF200         2
  3         ABC100         1
  4         ABC100         1
  5         DEF200         2
```

As you see **ABC100** is repeating so its having item_number 1 and **DEF200** is 2 and so on. Can anyone help me how to achieve this?. I have searched on google nothing found.

Comment: Why do you open another request? This is not very different from the Question you asked yesterday. Why don't you answer our questions? Why are you ignoring us who want to help. This is not very polite. So again: What are your requirements for the item_number? Must it start with 1? Must it be the least code that gets #1? Or the first code? Or is the first (ordered by ID) always the least? Or do you merely want unique numbers? Could we give ABC100 number 2 and DEF200 number 1 instead? Are gaps allowed? Could we give ABC100 number 10 and DEF200 number 50? Tell us the requirements.

Comment: It looks kind of strange that you are looking for a unique number for a code, because the code itself is already a unique identifier so to say. What do you gain by this 1:1 relation between code and number? Why can't you just say the code *is* the item number?

Answer (score 1):

For versions of MySQL earlier than 8, you can use variables to simulate `ROW_NUMBER()` functionality. The subquery here assigns an item number according to whether the `material_code` is the same as the previous row, working with data sorted by `material_code`. We then `SELECT` everything from the subquery, ordering by `id` again.

```
SELECT id, material_code, item_number
FROM (SELECT id, 
             @i := (CASE WHEN @m = material_code THEN @i ELSE @i + 1 END) AS item_number,
             @m := material_code AS material_code
      FROM carts
      JOIN (SELECT @m := '', @i := 0) v
      ORDER BY material_code) c
ORDER BY id
```

Output:

```
id  material_code   item_number
1   ABC100          1
2   DEF200          2
3   ABC100          1
4   ABC100          1
5   DEF200          2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6679de7d6cd71a76f2dcda4d1041be18)

Comment: when i do insted of  order by ORDER BY material_code) c  to ORDER BY id) c its not working

Comment: @kunal that is correct, it only works if you `ORDER BY material_code`. That's why I use a subquery and then an outer query to `ORDER BY id`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options you can try.

1. Don't use the key word Distinct - When you use distinct for select queries , the result removes the duplicate rows.

   Select id , material_number , 
   Case 
    When  material_number='ABC100' Then 1
    When material_number ='DEF200' Then 2
   End As item_number
   From table1
2. If you get the union of two tables then you can use Union All instead of Union. Because Union All dose not remove the duplicate rows.

   Select id , material_number , 
   Case 
    When  material_number='ABC100' Then 1
    When material_number ='DEF200' Then 2
   End As item_number
   From table1
   Union All 
   Select id , material_number , 
   Case 
    When  material_number='ABC100' Then 1
    When material_number ='DEF200' Then 2
   End As item_number
   From table2

Comment: can you post sql query?

Comment: why you pass material_code static

Comment: Isn't the material_code is a column of the table and having those values ?

Comment: i mean why you pass material_code = ABC100

Comment: Because according to the value of the material_code we have to set the value of the  item_number

Comment: no suppose i have 1 lakh material code how i can do?

Comment: Then you have to get the  distinct material_codes from a seperate select query and and insert them into a another table and set an incremental column for that table to set the item_number. Then you can join your table with the newly created table.

Answer (score 0):

If mysql version is 8+, then we can use analytic function rank()

```
select id, material_code, rank() over (partition by material_code order by material_code) as itemNumber from table;
```

Comment: An alias was previously found. (near "itemNumber" at position 69)
An alias was expected. (near " " at position 68)
Unexpected token. (near "itemNumber" at position 69)

Answer (score 0):

**Material**

```
id(Auto Increment)     material_code
1                      ABC100
2                      DEF200
```

**Cart**

```
id     material_code
1         ABC100
2         DEF200
3         ABC100
4         ABC100
5         DEF200
```

**Query**

```
SELECT c.id, c.material_code, m.id AS item_number FROM cart AS c JOIN material AS m ON c.material_code = m.material_code
```

Comment: what is join material?

Comment: Hii Kunal, do you have material table? if so add auto increment field in your material table, and join that table with cart table while selecting data, look at my query above.

Comment: i have only carts table

Comment: i have no material master table.. actually data i coming from  SAP

Comment: ohh then you should try Nick's answer